# PHP: Need to close STDIN in order to read STDOUT?

Tags: php, linux

I recently tried to communicate with a binary on my Ubuntu webserver [1] using the PHP function proc_open. I can establish a connection and define the pipes STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR. Nice.

Now the bimary I am talking to is an interactive computer algebra software - therefore I would like to keep both STDOUT and STDIN alive after the first command such that I can still use the application a few lines later in an interactive manner (direct user inputs from a web-frontend).

However, as it turns out, the PHP functions to read the STDOUT of the binary (either stream_get_contents or fgets) need a closed STDIN before they can work. Otherwise the program deadlocks.

This is a severe drawback since I can not just reopen the closed STDIN after closing it. So my question is: why does my script deadlock if I want to read the STDOUT when my STDIN is still alive?

Thanks
Jens

[1] [proc_open returns false but does not write in error file - permissions issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805645/proc-open-returns-false-but-does-not-write-in-error-file-permissions-issue)

my source:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe","r"),
    1 => array("pipe","w"),
    2 => array("file","./error.log","a")
) ;

// define current working directory where files would be stored
$cwd = './' ;

// open reduce
$process = proc_open('./reduce/reduce', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd) ;

if (is_resource($process)) {

    // some valid Reduce commands
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'load excalc; operator x; x(0) := t; x(1) := r;');

    // if the following line is removed, the script deadlocks
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo "output: " . stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);

    // close pipes & close process
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);

}
```

EDIT:

This code kind of works. Kind of because it uses usleeps to wait for the non-blocked STDOUT to be filled with data. How do I do that more elegantly?

@ Elias: By polling the $status['running'] entry you can only determine if the overall process is still running, but not if the process is busy or idling... That is why I have to include these usleeps.

```
define('TIMEOUT_IN_MS', '100');
define('TIMEOUT_STEPS', '100');

function getOutput ($pipes) {
    $result = "";
    $stage = 0;
    $buffer = 0;
    do {
        $char = fgets($pipes[1], 4096);
        if ($char != null) {
            $buffer = 0;
            $stage = 1;
            $result .= $char;
        } else if ($stage == "1") {
            usleep(TIMEOUT_IN_MS/TIMEOUT_STEPS);
            $buffer++;
            if ($buffer > TIMEOUT_STEPS) {
                $stage++;
            }
        }
    } while ($stage < 2);
    return $result;
}

$descriptorspec = array( 0 => array("pipe", "r"), 1 => array("pipe", "w") ) ;

// define current working directory where files would be stored
$cwd = './' ;

// open reduce
$process = proc_open('./reduce/reduce', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);

if (is_resource($process)) {

    stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);

    echo "startup output:<br><pre>" . getOutput($pipes) . "</pre>";

    fwrite($pipes[0], 'on output; load excalc; operator x; x(0) := t; x(1) := r;' . PHP_EOL);
    echo "output 1:<br><pre>" . getOutput($pipes) . "</pre>";

    fwrite($pipes[0], 'coframe o(t) = sqrt(1-2m/r) * d t, o(r) = 1/sqrt(1-2m/r) * d r with metric g = -o(t)*o(t) + o(r)*o(r); displayframe;' . PHP_EOL);
    echo "output 2:<br><pre>" . getOutput($pipes) . "</pre>";

    // close pipes & close process
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);

}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow: the entry $pipes[0] is a handle to a stream that is connected to the STDIN of my binary. I can emulate all kind of inputs and what I get works. But I have to close $pipes[0] before I read from $pipes[1]. I cannot just load content from a file because the session is required to be interactive, so that is not an option.

Comment: Ignore that, I have an idea, not sure if it'll work, but it's too much to write in a comment, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reminds me of [a script I wrote a while back](https://github.com/EVODelavega/gp-scripts/blob/master/autoRepeat.php). While it might serve as inspiration to you (or others), it doesn't do what you need. What it *does* contain is an example of how you can read the output of a stream, without having to close any of the streams.
Perhaps you can apply the same logic to your situation:

```
$allInput = array(
    'load excalc; operator x; x(0) := t; x(1) := r;'
);//array with strings to pass to proc
if (is_resource($process))
{
    $output = '';
    $input = array_shift($allInput);
    do
    {
        usleep(200);//make sure the running process is ready
        fwrite(
            $pipes,
            $input.PHP_EOL,//add EOL
            strlen($input)+1
        );
        fflush($pipes[0]);//flush buffered data, write to stream
        usleep(200);
        $status = proc_get_status($process);
        while($out = fread($pipes[1], 1024) && !feof($pipes[1])) 
            $output .= $out;
    } while($status['running'] && $input = array_shift($allInput));
    //proc_close & fclose calls here
}
```

Now, seeing as I don't know what it is exactly you are trying to do, this code will need to be tweaked quite a bit. You may, for example, find yourself having to set the STDIN and STDOUT pipes as non-blocking.
It's a simple matter of adding this, right after calling `proc_open`, though:

```
 stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], 0);
 stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
```

Play around, have fun, and perhaps let me know if this answer was helpful in any way...

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try and let you know here.

Comment: I am having trouble... What I want is quite simple. I want to emulate the exact interaction with the program that you have in a shell, but it should be in a website frontend. So there is one textarea with the program's output, and below that one textfield for user input, and next to it a "send" button - you get the idea. I used the code you provided, but it still deadlocks. If I set STDIN and STDOUT to non-blocking mode, I get empty results.

Comment: @Jens: I know that `proc_get_status` only tells you if the program is still running, but that's why I included it: no point in sending input to a process that no longer exists. The main suggestions I made were: add `PHP_EOL`, call `stream_set_blocking($stream, 0);` to force non-blocking streams, use `usleep` to give the process time to react, and use `fgets` to read chunks from the stream. Looking at your edit, I'm inclined to say that my suggestions did serve you rather well, no?

Comment: Yes, of course, and I am very greatful you did. But polling the STDIN with usleeps as pauses is a rather unelegant method, isn't it? That is why I asked for a method to determine if a pipe is busy or not.

Comment: @Jens: There is no such method available, AFAIK. PHP wasn't designed to excel at tasks like this, so it's only natural this all feels a bit quirky, and hacky

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you're doing everything correctly, *except* that the binary is never notified that it has received all the input and can start to work. By closing STDIN, you're kicking off the work process, because it's clear that there will be no more input. If you're not closing STDIN, the binary is waiting for more input, while your side is waiting for its output.

You probably need to **end your input with a newline** or whatever other protocol action is expected of you. Or perhaps closing STDIN is *the* action that's expected of you. Unless the process is specifically created to stay open and continue to stream input, you can't make it do it. If the process reads all input, processes it, returns output and then quits, there's no way you can make it stay alive to process more input later. If the process explicitly supports that behaviour, there should be a definition on how you need to delimit your input.

Comment: It is an interactive shell application, so I strongly assume that there should be a valid delimiter. PHP_EOL won't do it, though, I tried it already. And reopening the STDIN? Is that an idea? I mean, fclose it first, and then fopen it again? That doesn't work straightforwardly, so is there a hidden pitfall I don't see?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to reopen the pipe, since there's no way to pass the read end back to the process after the fact. Try with more delimiters.

Comment: It turned out that PHP_EOL is just fine. See my post below. edit: can't do that yet. See instead my edit in my original post above.