# passing string from c++ to php script

Tags: php, c++

I'm trying to pass parameters between php script and c++ program.
my php script looks like this

```
<?php
    $ip = $_GET["q"];
    $array = str_getcsv($ip);
    foreach($array as $line){
        exec("./a.exe", $line, $output);
        echo $output;
    }
?>
```

then I want my c++ program to return me a string(but I really have no idea how to do it), can you help with this?

Comment: It looks like PHP wants to have the standard output of the `a.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you're going about this the right way... but to answer your question (getting a string that is put out by an executable), it's really quite simple:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("This is a line\n");
    puts("Another line");
    stc::cout << "Last bit";
    return 0;
}
```

The code above, when compiled can be executed through `exec`. The function's signature can be found [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

Tells you that it returns a string (being the last line of output of the command), assigns an array (representing each line of output) to the second argument, and the exit code is assigned to the third argument, so:

```
$last = exec('./a.exe', $full, $status);
if ($status != 0) {
    echo 'Something didn\'t go quite right';
} else {
    echo 'Last line of output was: ', $last, PHP_EOL,
         'The full output looked like this: ', PHP_EOL,
         implode(PHP_EOL, $full);
}
```

To enable actual *interaction* with the running program, you'll have to ditch `exec`, `shell_exec`, `passthru` and any of those functions. They're just not up to the job. What yo probably really want is something like [the `proc_open` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). This way, you can access the `stderr`, `stdin` and `stdout` streams your program uses, and write to the `stdin`, effectively interacting with the process.

Based on the first example given in the docs, this is worth a shot:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a")
);

$process = proc_open('./a.exe', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (!is_resource($process))
    exit(1);//error
foreach ($array as $line) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], $line."\n");//added the EOL, just in case
    fflush($pipes[0]);//flush
    usleep(100);//wait for a bit
    //unsure about this bit, though, perhaps fread is a better choice
    $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);//get output
    fflush($pipes[0]);//reminds me a bit of fflush(stdin) though. So I'd probably leave this out
}
array_map('fclose', $pipes);//close streams
proc_close($process);
```

See if this works for you, look at the docs, and find some `proc_open` examples. Some time ago, I've written a PHP script that automatically repeats a command, until something is written to the stderr stream. I've put the code up on [github](https://github.com/EVODelavega/gp-scripts/blob/master/autoRepeat.php) so it might be worth a look, I've also linked to the source from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826537/php-need-to-close-stdin-in-order-to-read-stdout)